# Flutter Gridview.builder card how to create empty cards or space based on on dynamic weekdays?

Tags: flutter, gridview

I'm trying to build a custom 'calendar' card view with Gridview.builder by assigning weekdays on the right (can be seen on the screenshot).

The list of days(cards) will increment each day because it's based on DateTime.now()

Based on the day I need to generate space between cards so the calendar is correct.

Here is some code that I'm using:

[image: Flutter custom calendar with gridview builder]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class CalendarUI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 04, 10);

    getDaysInBetween() {
      final int difference = startDate.difference(endDate).inDays;
      print(difference);
      return difference;
    }

    final items = List<DateTime>.generate(getDaysInBetween(), (i) {
      DateTime date = endDate;

      return date.add(Duration(days: i));
    });

    var newList = items.reversed.toList();

    getDaysInBetween();

    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: GridView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                reverse: true,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 7,
                ),
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int key) {
                  return Card(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('${newList[key].day}'),
                      ));
                }),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: 350,
            minHeight: 350,
          ),
          child: Column(
            // crossAxisAlignment: ,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Spacer(flex: 1),
              Text('Mon'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Tue'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Wed'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Thu'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Fri'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Sat'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Sun'),
              Spacer(flex: 1),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented empty space by calculating with weekday of today.

1. Calculating weekday to add empty card
   If today is 'Monday', DateTime.now().weekday is 1.
   So we need to 0 empty container when today is 'Monday'.
   The value what I want is that 'DateTime.now().weekday - 1'.
2. add empty cards as amount of weekday number when build GridView.
3. Increasing 'itemCount' as amount of weekday value.
4. Because add emtpy cards and increased 'itemCount', should change data indexing value.

The attachment was made on 7/13 Tuesday.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return CalendarUI();
  }
}

class CalendarUI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 04, 10);
    // weekday value is Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1...Sunday = 6
    int weekday = DateTime.now().weekday - 1;

    getDaysInBetween() {
      final int difference = startDate.difference(endDate).inDays;
      print(difference);
      return difference;
    }

    final items = List<DateTime>.generate(getDaysInBetween(), (i) {
      DateTime date = endDate;

      return date.add(Duration(days: i));
    });

    var newList = items.reversed.toList();

    getDaysInBetween();

    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: GridView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                reverse: true,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 7,
                ),
                itemCount: items.length + weekday,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int key) {
                  if (key < weekday) {
                    return Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    );
                  } else {
                    int index = key - weekday;
                    print(key);
                    return Card(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text('${newList[index].day} / index: $index'),
                        ));
                  }
                }),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: 350,
          ),
          child: Column(
            // crossAxisAlignment: ,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Spacer(flex: 1),
              Text('Mon'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Tue'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Wed'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Thu'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Fri'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Sat'),
              Spacer(flex: 2),
              Text('Sun'),
              Spacer(flex: 1),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've got it working today. Your implementation needs to hide the empty cards(they appear white and are visible to the user). I will post my solution below soon, but it requires conditional rendering and two cards.

Comment: I just used Card widget instead of empty Container widget for convenient.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll merge your solution today with my own. Hopefully it will help others too :-)